# Elasticsearch timeout problems

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just started indexing pdf/word documents and some of them can get rather big. To make things worse, I'm using n-grams in my index analyzer. I have 8GB of RAM dedicated to ElasticSearch but our index is presently about 45GB big (was only about 6GB without documents) Which leads me to my problem ...

After we added documents to our index, reindexing everything started taking much longer, which is to be expected, but it also started failing randomly with a generic timeout error. I traced the problem to our http client (HTTParty ruby gem) which had a default timeout of 10s. I increased it to 480s and the reindex gets to more documents but still times out eventually.

My question is,

1. should Elasticsearch take that long to respond to an index request?
2. What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: 1. Yes faced similar problems here and realized it runs out of heap space very soon once it starts slowing. 2. Try increasing the heap size. All the best :)

Comment: Definitely check heap space to rule out possible memory issues. It would be also nice if you could add results of [hot_threads](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-nodes-hot-threads/) request to your question. Please, run this query while indexing is going on.

Comment: Besides heap size you may want to check replication. If replication is on turn it off, set it to zero, then once you are done indexing turn it back on.

Comment: Are you using the reindex API? make sure to use `wait_for_completion=false`, as explained here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api